# Why is my animation exported from ArcGlobe not playing?

Tags: export, animation, arcglobe

The exporting process has finished and an avi file was created. When I try playing it, it raises an error in WMP as well as VLC. VLC gives me some information: "audio or video format not supported "undf"

I am exporting with no compression to avi.

Oh yeah, and unfortunately there is no way to fix this....

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: AVI is a container format - but VLC will play all MP4 containers - http://www.avitomp4.net/

Comment: Unfortunately, AVI is the only export option out of ArcGlobe. That and sequential images.

Comment: I wonder if the file size might be affecting this. Could you try exporting a shorter section and seeing if this worked?

Comment: Is this problem occurring on the same computer that you used to export the AVI from ArcGlobe?

Comment: I tried exporting several clips of varying lengths and using a different codec and the outcome is always the same.  @Kevin - yes, I play this on the same computer.

Comment: @Kevin - tried on a second machine. Video raises the same error in WMP and it does not play in VLC but no error.

Comment: @Jakub - Was curious if maybe a codec was missing, but that shouldn't be the case if playing the AVI on the same computer that created it.

Comment: I am having better luck exporting short clips that use only 2 keyframes. If i keep it under 30 seconds and the resulting file is less then 2GB the video seems to work (still jaggedy) but i can at least merge clips together and speed them up in post processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use the Full Frames (Uncompressed) option to export a short test clip to AVI. It played fine in Windows Media Player, and VLC played it but with some strange distortion. There might be something funny with your setup that's not really within the scope of this site to troubleshoot, but as a starting point use [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to determine what codec the AVI file contains, and [GraphEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphEdit) to figure out what decoding path your system is attempting to use to play it.

Also you could try using [x264vfw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/) as your codec, which VLC will definitely play and it will perform/compress much better than the default installed compressors.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaWUu.png) are the x264 settings that worked well for playback in both VLC and WMP.

Comment: I tried something simple as well. (Just used default layers and made a few keyframes) No Problems, video exports as expected.  IN my actual project I have LiDAR surface, 5x vertical exaggerations and draped custom aerial imagery.  I guess ArcGLobe chokes when I add real data to it.  I tried cashing every layer before which took 2 days and then crashed when I tried to export the video.

Comment: Ahh yeah, ArcGlobe is not very good when it comes to large amounts of data. What kind of framerate do you get when you run your animation without exporting it? You could try capturing your viewport using MSI Afterburner, FRAPS or other similar application.

Comment: Sigh. That is not a good news. Thanks man. When I just play it the frame rate isn't good enough to capture the quality I need.

Comment: Camtasia may also be a good choice for capturing the vid as it plays in Globe.

Comment: Sounds like you need something more purpose-built. I'd be interesting in hearing with what you end up using. I'm sure there are LiDAR importers/plug-ins for the more popular 3D modeling packages out there like 3D Studio, Maya, etc.

Comment: There is some good info in a few questions in regards to flyover animations I've posted recently. Blender keeps coming up and also Vue but i am a bit hesitant about the steep learning curve as these do not conform to the typical windows application design standard. Most of these are designed for virtual reality worlds but they do take in DEM input as well.

Comment: You might also try [QT Modeler](http://www.appliedimagery.com/), it was mentioned in another thread: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/what-are-limits-on-arcscene-and-lidar

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possibly relevant suggestions from [this site](http://www.gsd.harvard.edu/gis/manual/globetrouble/index.htm).

1. **Keep the ArcGlobe window small.** This will yield smaller dimensions and perhaps less detail in the exported AVI. However, it may reveal that the resultant AVI was too large (it was >4 GB) and/or complex.
2. **Produce a simple video with one or two simple layers and low quality.** If the output works then gradually up the framerate, 3D marker details and layers.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. Take a look at my comment to blah238's answer.  Simple video works fine but my project needs to include full resolution LiDAR surface and high resolution aerial imagery @ 5x vertical exaggeration. (So far there is nothing else besides these few layers and 3 labels) Animation plays fine in ArcGLobe and seems to be exporting without any errors, I just cannot play the final video from my actual project.  Also, the final video needs to be very high quality. If ArcGlobe is choking this early into the project then it might not be the tool for the job.

Comment: "If ArcGlobe is choking this early into the project then it might not be the tool for the job." I found the same thing when using Globe on a project a few years ago. The final vid was acceptable/good, but much less detailed than I originally imagined it would be.

Comment: I've used google earth pro for high-definition video exports previously without problems. It's surprisingly quick to render the videos also.

Comment: Can I load higher definition surface data into Google Earth Pro and drape my own aerial imagery?  If so it would work because i work with Sketchup as well and the SketchUp Google Earth integration is quite seamless...